# Support for importing Windows Phone Apps with the "Add Project" tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Using the **Add Project** tool to add a Windows Phone project to the **Apps & Software** section of my Careers 2.0 profile, I get the following error `Sorry, we could not retrieve that URL for some reason.`

I have tried using the the so-called "[deep link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967553(v=vs.92).aspx)", and the US store link, to the app in the Windows Phone Marketplace.

Are there any plans to support this marketplace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be resolved, please give it another try?

Comment: That was fast, worked great! Thank you.

Comment: This is done :)